# Video não abre em DIV

Tags: javascript

Eu estou substituindo meus IFRAMES por DIVS, mas eu notei que não é exibido uma barra de rolagem quando a pagina é extensa e tambem não é exibido os players dos videos da minha pagina dentro das DIV principal chamada conteudo, porque ?

Segue meu codigo:

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
try{  
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();  
}  
catch(ee){  
try{  
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");  
}  
catch(e){  
try{  
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
}  
catch(E){  
xmlhttp = false;  
}  
}  
}  
div_base = "";  
function abre(arquivo,metodo,div){  
div_base = div;  
xmlhttp.open(metodo,arquivo);  
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=conteudo  
xmlhttp.send(null)  
}  
function conteudo() {  
nova_div = div_base;  
document.getElementById(nova_div).innerHTML="<div style='top:50%;left:50%;
position:absolute; overflow:auto;'>carregando...</div>"  
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4){  
document.getElementById(nova_div).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText  
}  
}  
</script>
```

**html**

```
<a href="javascript: abre('minha_pagina.html','GET','conteudo');">
Minha   Pagina</a>

<div id="conteudo"></div>
```

Obrigado